# pug how to set dynamic src

Tags: image, dynamic, pug

```
script.
  let thisfilefullname = document.URL.substring(document.URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, document.URL.lastIndexOf('.'));
  let imgurl = './img';
  if(thisfilefullname.indexOf('localhost') == -1  && thisfilefullname != 'index') { imgurl = '../img'; } //'localhost' will be changed
h1.head_logo
  a(href="/", title="홈으로 이동")
    img(src= imgurl+"/logo.png", alt="description") //imgurl : undfined
```

Is there no way to inline some variables to pug?
Should I use 'document.getElementById(...)'?

Answer (score 0):

Pug compiles server-side before any code is sent to the browser. Pug attribute interpolation (in other words, things like `src= imgurl`) is evaluated as part of that compiling process.

In contrast, the JavaScript you've written inside that `script` tag runs client-side, in the browser, *after* Pug has fully compiled. Pug doesn't have access to variables defined in client-side JavaScript, and doesn't have access to `document`, because it doesn't exist yet.

In short, your current code tries to use variables on the server that don't get defined until after compilation has happened and Pug is no longer part of the picture.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I created a separate head for each index and sub pages. And I made it compile using the pug variable on each page.

Comment: @강한구 If this answer aided you, please click accept and upvote it